# Elements doesn't show up with custom adapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

So, I wanted customize elements from my Listview and I made a custom adapter.

```
public class elementList extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public elementList(Context context, String[] data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, null);
    TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Log.d("TAG", "DA");
    text.setText(data[position]);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Here is my main activity

```
private void showTasks(){
    final ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>(taskList);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasks);
    final elementList element = new elementList(this, tasks.toArray(new String[0]));
    listView.setAdapter(element);

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference adress = database.getReference("users/" + user.getUid() + "/tasksList");
    adress.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try{
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                    Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : value.entrySet()){
                        tasks.add(entry.getValue());
                        Log.d("VALOARE", entry.getValue());
                        element.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show up my list if I am using my adapter (element), but it's working fine if I use arrayadapter.

[image: using arrayadapter]
[image: using element]

In the first picture I am using arrayadapter and in the second element. I want to mentiont that it doesn't crash or give any error.

Comment: I find the `static` layout inflater suspicious. Also check https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/ on how to pass the parent view to the `inflate` method.

Comment: The array backing your `elementList` `Adapter` is never changed/updated. You make an array copy of the `tasks` `List` once when it's empty, but never alter the array after that. Updating that `List` isn't going to do anything to that array. Why not make your custom `Adapter` take a `List` instead, so you can update it the same way you are the `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Share your task.xml layout

Comment: @MikeM. how can i use list in my adapter?

Comment: Change `String[]` to `List<String>`, `data.length` to `data.size()`, `data[position]` to `data.get(position)`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the call to the `ValueEventListener` callback modifies `tasks`, but the `element` adapter is not using `tasks` as its source of data. It is using an array copied from it obtained by calling `.toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the list values as an array. Pass the Arraylist task  to the custom adapter which you modify in the showTasks () method.

Use this

```
 final elementList element = new elementList(this, tasks);
```

instead of

```
final elementList element = new elementList(this, tasks.toArray(new String[0]));
```

And change your custom adapter contructor to take the value of arraylist instead of string array.